# return object from method in class

Tags: c#, object, methods

I have a code which is made of 2 classes. inside the `class Program` there is a method names `calculate` which should get 3 strings and return an object:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class DataGridObject
    {
        public string MainName { get; set; }
        public double Level { get; set; }
        public double Exp { get; set; }
        public double AmountNeed { get; set; }
        public double TotalLose { get; set; }
        public double TotalGain { get; set; }
        public double TotalCost { get; set; }
        public Uri ImageSource { get; set; }

    }

   public static class Program
    {

            public object calculate(string db_name, string sheetname, string images_path)
            {

            string DataBase_File = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(),     String.Format("{0}",db_name));
            string SheetName = string.Format("{0}$",sheetname);
            string Images_File = string.Format(@"{0}",images_path);

            ***//some code in between which reads url, parsing json and do some math on the data in order to store it in `var d`//*** 

            var L = new List<DataGridObject>();

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Images_File);

            for (int z = 0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
              {
                var d = new DataGridObject();

                d.MainName = ...;
                d.Level = ...;
                d.Exp = ...;
                d.AmountNeed = ...;
                d.TotalLose = ...;
                d.TotalGain = ....;
                d.TotalCost = ....;
                d.ImageSource = new Uri....;

                L.Add(d);

              }

            return L;

          }


//calling the method:

    string db_name = "DataBase.xlsx";
    string sheetname = "sheet1";
    string images_path = "C:\\Users...";

    object a = calculate(db_name, sheetname, images_path);

}
```

The error i get is at the line where i call the method:

"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,method or property `Program.db_name`" and same for the 2 others (Program.sheetname, Program.images_path)

Comment: why have you got semi-colons between the method arguments? "object a = calculate(string db_name; string sheetname; string images_path);"

Comment: The error you've provided doesn't match the code you've shown us and  this line would definitely produce an error that's different from the one you've shown us: `calculate(string db_name, string sheetname, string images_path);`.

Comment: @ben  I didn't say it would solve the problem. It wouldn't have compiled anyway as you showed it previously, It just didn't make sense.

Comment: You need to modify your question into an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue you're describing. Currently you have code that has ellipses everywhere, unclosed sections, and which would not under any circumstance produce the error you're describing.

Comment: Did you **read** the linked MVCE help? Don't try to piecemeal "fix" the code you're showing. Spend time creating a *minimal* but *complete* example and then post that here.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your function `calculate` is non `static` function and you may try to call it from a `static` function. So, please change your function to `static` like this:

```
public static object calculate(string db_name, string sheetname, string images_path)
```

Please check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx) for more details about `static` field and method.

Comment: changed, thank you. now the error is in the 3 parameters in the method (Program.db_name,Program.sheetname,Program.iamges_path)

Comment: You have to change your variable to `static`.